# Is there's any way for finding the angle between camera and plane in sceneform

Tags: android, sceneform

I'm working on a project in which I'm want to find the angle between camera of the device and ar plane like 0,90,180 etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm doing project on Ar. I want to find angle between the ar camera and node which places an object